# Lazysizes.js doesn't switch between responsive images?

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading

I'm trying to get the lazysizes.js plugin working (https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes)

On my images I have:

```
<img data-srcset="medium.jpg 768w, small.jpg 634w" data-src="small.jpg 634w" data-size="auto" class="lazyload">
```

However, to matter what size screen I view it on it always seems to use the `medium.jpg` image size.

I'm really puzzled how to set Lazyload up.

Would anyone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was missing the rest of the plugin to allow for responsive images

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aFarkas/lazysizes/gh-pages/plugins/respimg/ls.respimg.min.js?_sm_au_=iVVn40qnDsfHN1NKK6tqCK7NC1kF2